# Bazel coverage needs jdk, why I cannot use jdk-home given by bazel info?

Tags: java, code-coverage, bazel

If I want to run `bazel coverage` I need to add a rule to specify a jdk tool.
https://bazel.build/configure/coverage#running_coverage

But why can't I give the jdk used by bazel and for which the path is given with `bazel info java-home` ?

why to load another jdk when this one is avalaible.... ??

Adding in WORKSPACE

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:local_java_repository.bzl", "local_java_repository")

local_java_repository(
  name = "additionaljdk",          # Can be used with --java_runtime_version=additionaljdk, --java_runtime_version=11 or --java_runtime_version=additionaljdk_11
  version = "11",                    # Optional, if not set it is autodetected
  java_home = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/",  # Path to directory containing bin/java
)
```

it will run
is there a way to set in the previous rule something to point inside `$(bazel info java-home)` please ?

```
java_home=(locate $java-home)
```

thanks

I'd like to avoid installing another jdk as it is installed by bazel itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `bazel info java-home` command prints the path to the Java installation used to run Bazel itself. This Java is conceptually completely distinct from a Java that may be used by the actions that Bazel runs in a build. Bazel ships with a stripped-down, minimal JRE for itself that is not suitable for usage by build actions.

If your concern about installing a JDK is simply the inconvenience, you can use [`--java_runtime_version=remotejdk_11`](https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual#java_runtime_version) to have Bazel pull in a JDK for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Benjamin! for your answer